# How do I execute a linux command in PHP and echo the output in original format?

Tags: php, linux, shell

How do I execute a linux command in PHP and echo the output in original format?

```
$out = shell_exec('df');
echo $out;
```

It seems that this simple method will only print the output in a long string format rather than with the correct number of spaces, tabs, line separators. Any assistance is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a browser:

```
echo "<pre>$out</pre>";
```

Browsers render HTML.  Whitespace has no meaning in HTML, only to format the source.  `pre` tags instruct the browser to render the text as pre-formatted text.

Comment: that works! I'd like echo out [crontab -l] as well, however, I don't believe the webpage has permission to execute that command. Any suggestions? Thanks!